# How to show Spinning Modal in WPF

Tags: wpf, modal-dialog, font-awesome, spinning

I have an application which contain below code in its MainWindow.xaml to show the spinning modal using FontAwesome icon:

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding SpinningModalVisibility}">
        <StackPanel>
            <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Spinner" Spin="True" SpinDuration="5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

and in ViewModel, I will call

```
SpinningModalVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (Action)(() =>
{
   //MyAction
}));
SpinningModalVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

but for some reason, my icon is not spinning, and the modal does not behave correctly; sometime it show, sometime does not. Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: first of all, Visibility.Visible must not be in your viewmodel; you must use a boolean and a converter....then  what is </TextBlock> in the stackpanel ? - typo ?

Comment: Hi @GCamel, you are correct, I just post the simplify version of my code to make it simple. I edited the question, does you have any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: SpinningModalVisibility  is a property that send the IPropertyChanged...add this code, pls - also this code Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(...must not be in your viewmodel if related to the view...

Comment: SpinDuration is your problem ! it start from the load of the grid...not from the visibility change..! test with 10000000

Comment: you 'd better bind Spin="{Binding IsLoading}" to your view model

Comment: Hi @GCamel, I used Prism MVVM and have:
public Visibility SpinningModalVisibility
        {
            get { return _spinningModalVisibility; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _spinningModalVisibility, value); }
        }
to refresh my UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perform the action on a background thread. The UI thread cannot both display the spinner and run your code at the same time:

```
SpinningModalVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> 
{
    //YourAction();
}).ContinueWith(Task => 
{
    SpinningModalVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Answer (score -1):

SpinDuration=5 is your problem !

it start from the load of the usercontrol/grid...not from the visibility change..! test with bigger value

Comment: thank but this does not solve my issue, I used @mm8 code and it worked fine for me

Comment: why not....it is true that your action code can freeze the gui; but you are doing it wrong : your spin control is always running (means having a timer in back; but display nothing) and Visibility must not be in the viewmodel